# Laravel - Execute single query with multiple databases

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I'm writing an archival function in a Laravel site and I can't figure out how to replicate this query using Laravel's query builder. My databases are 'archive' and 'live'.

```
INSERT INTO archive.daily_by_post 
SELECT post_date, user_id, post_id 
    FROM live.clicks 
    WHERE timestamp BETWEEN '2014-07-28 00:00:00' AND '2014-07-28 23:59:59' 
    GROUP BY user_id, post_id;
```

Should I use a different method? Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible of course.

However you need to build your query either using raw statement OR `Connection::insert()` mixed with `Query\Builder` like below:

```
$from = '2014-07-30 00:00:00';
$till = '2014-07-30 23:59:59';

$select = DB::table('live.clicks')
        ->select('post_date', 'user_id', 'post_id')
        ->whereBetween('updated_at', [$from, $till]) // empty array will do
        ->groupBy('user_id', 'post_id');

$statement = 'INSERT INTO archive.daily_by_post (specify fields if necessary) '
    . $select->toSql(); 

DB::insert($statement, $select->getBindings());
```

Comment: Thanks deczo. Wouldn't this split the query into 2 transactions instead of it being just 1? I already have code to do that. I am really looking for a way to minimize the number of transactions run.

Comment: No, it will run exactly the same query as the one you pasted. Transaction is completely different thing.